# UINavigationController hides AVPlayerViewController progress slider

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, avplayerviewcontroller

I'm using AVPlayerViewController with the UINavigationController like following code.

```
AVPlayerViewController* audioPlayer = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
audioPlayer.audioFilePath = recordFilePath;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:audioPlayer animated:YES];
```

When the AVPlayerViewController appeared, the progress slider had been hidden by the UINavigationBar control.

How can I show the progress slider along with the UINavigationBar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the navigation bar's translucent property to "NO" in your `viewDidLoad`

`self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;`

It will start the view from being framed underneath the navigation bar and status bar. Hence you can see `AVPlayerViewController` progress slider.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad    
{       
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    [self performSelector:@selector(PlayVideo) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0];
}

-(void)PlayVideo    
{         
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"];

    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];    
    AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
    playerViewController.player = player;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:playerViewController animated:YES];
}
```

[The progress slider will shown at the bottom of the device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ubp3.png)

Comment: My problem was solved by @byJeevan and your answer. Thank you.